# sterographic projection of complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, stereographic-projections

How author arrives at last step in following picture?[image] How author arrives at $t=\frac{|z|^2}{1+|z|^2}$.

My attempt: since we see in pic that $(1-t)^2|z|^2=t(1-t)$ from this we conclude that, $t=(1-t)|z|^2$ but on other hand author arrives at $t=\frac{|z|^2}{1+|z|^2}$ How? Please help

Comment: how would you solve $t=(1-t)\cdot5$ for $t$ ? Then do the same with 5 replaced by $|z|^2$.

Comment: @Mihail why author consider the restriction that, the point must be **not ** equals to $(0,0,1)$

Comment: your line passes through that point at $t=1$, so you cannot divide both sides by $(1-t)$.

Answer (score 1):

From $(1−t)^2|z|^2=t(1−t)$ divide the whole equation by $(1-t)$ just like you did! :)

$(1−t)^2|z|^2=t(1−t)$ /:$(1-t)$

$|z|^2 (1-t)= t$

Now multiply the brackets on the left side and you get:

$|z|^2 - t|z|^2 = t$

$|z|^2 = t +  t|z|^2$

$ |z|^2 = t(1+|z|^2)$

And finally:

$ t = |z|^2 / (1+|z|^2)$